Why in Mudblazor's MudAutoComplete , styles applied in dropdown list cannot be applied to the selected text
I am using Mudautocomplete in Mudblazor , My autocomplete works fine but I want to bind two values to the list , where second one is mentioned in bracket. Now I changed the font size of the text in bracket it got applied in drop down list but when I select a value , the styles are not applied there.How to apply specific styles of the drop down item in selected values.
This is my code.
 <MudAutocomplete T="ApplicationTable" Label="Enter Application ID or Name"
             Style="margin-bottom:25px" Value="@values"
             ToStringFunc="@(e=> e==null?null : $"{e.ApplicationName} ({e.AppInfoId})")" 
             Variant="Variant.Outlined" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter" Margin="Margin.Dense"
             SearchFunc="(string searchText) => SearchAutoComplete(searchText)"
             AutoFocus="true" Clearable="true" ValueChanged="OnValueChanged"
             Disabled="isDisableAutoComplete" ResetValueOnEmptyText="true" ItemSelectedTemplate="ItemSelectedTemplate"
             ItemTemplate="ItemTemplate" For="@(() => AppIdorName)" Required="true" RequiredError="App ID or Name is required!" />

I have added the sample code snippet below
Try snippet



I don't know about MudBlazor, but isn't it "style" instead of "Style" ?

What I mentioned in Style is working correct.In mudblazor its Style.

"but when I select a value , the styles are not applied there." - that's because the element that displays the selected value, is actually still an input field. You can not have two different font formatings in one single input field.

@CBroe I don't get it. What do you mean by  "two different font formatingsin one single input field."

You can not have two different text formatings, for the displayed value of a text input field. You can make the whole thing display in blue, you can make the whole thing display in cursive/italics ... But you can not make only "part of" the value display in one style, and another part in another style. There are no such "parts", this is one value.

@CBroe then how does it works in drop down items.Isn't it same there also

The dropdown part is not an input field, so you can actually use HTML in there. But the value of an input field can only be text.

@CBroe So is there any other method here

I don't think it's possible using that component.
